# How to interpret ないって

Tags: contractions

How to interpret **ないって** in the following sentence?

> アイスには賞味期限がないって本当ですか？

がない looks like negative form of ある, but what is って then? Can it be a contraction of quoting particle と?

Comment: って is short for というのは

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are parsing this incorrectly.  It is ない + って following after.  In this case, the って is a contraction of というのは, and the ない goes with 賞味期限が.

So the whole sentence parses like this:

> (アイスには賞味期限がない）って本当ですか？　→　Is it really true that ice cream doesn't have an expiration date?!